# Is there a way to access google business profile api for your own account without oauth2 verification? I just don't seem to find it online

Tags: api, google-business-profile-api

I am trying to create automation for my business using "Business profile APIs" but I can't use oauth2 verification. Is there a way to let's say get your business reviews without authentication? I don't seem to be able to figure it out. Thanks in advance

I have tried searching the documentations and I can find this
"GET [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews"](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/%7Bparent=accounts/*/locations/*%7D/reviews%22)
but I cant understand what to pass as parameters.